# Why does windows need the size when calling a function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to learn a little c++ and I have a silly question. Consider this code:

```
TCHAR tempPath[255];
GetTempPath(255, tempPath);
```

Why does windows need the size of the var tempPath? I see that the `GetTempPath` is declared something like:

```
GetTempPath(dword size, buf LPTSTR);
```

How can windows change the buf value without the `&` operator? Should not the function be like that?

```
GetTempPath(buf &LPTSTR);
```

Can somebody provide a simple `GetTempPath` implementation sample so I can see how `size` is used?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your answers, they are all correct and I gave you all +1. But what I meant by "Can somebody provide a simple `GetTempPath` implementation) is that i have tried to code a function similar to the one windows uses, as follow:

```
void MyGetTempPath(int size, char* buf) 
{
 buf = "C:\\test\\";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* tempPath = new TCHAR[255];
    GetTempPathA(255, tempPath);
    MessageBoxA(0, tempPath, "test", MB_OK);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But it does not work. MessageBox displays a "##$' string. How should MyGetTempPath be coded to work properly?

Comment: C++ has no built-in string type. Instead, you use character arrays and pointers. The statement `buf = "C:\\test\\"` copies the address of "C:\\test\\" to buff. However, since the pointer itself is passed by value, the caller's buf is not updated and it does nothing. Try using `strcpy_s` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows needs the size as a safety precaution. It could crash the application if it copies characters past the end of the buffer. When you supply the length, it can prevent that.

Array variables work like pointers. They point to the data in the array. So there is no need for the `&` operator.

Not sure what kind of example you are looking for. Like I said, it just needs to verify it doesn't write more characters than there's room for.

Comment: There's no need for `&` because there's an implicit conversion from an array to a pointer to the first element of the array, not because it *is* a pointer to the first element. Indeed, using `&` results in a pointer-to-array type, such as `int(*)[255]`.

Comment: @GMan: Can you clarify the difference between "works like a pointer" and "implicit conversion from an array to a pointer to the first element"? I can assure you I know exactly how it works. Are you arguing semantics?

Comment: @Johathan: First, because an array doesn't actually point to anything, it simply contains data. Second, there are circumstances under which the conversion from "name of array" to "pointer to beginning of array" doesn't happens, such as `sizeof(array)`. It's also important that you not confuse the two in an `extern` declaration: `extern int a[];` and `extern int *a;` are *not* the same.

Comment: @Jonathan: Hm, we may be arguing semantics, but I'll say my semantics are correct. :) Arrays are not pointers and do not work like pointers. There are cases where they may be converted to them, though. (If you think that means arrays work like pointers, then streams work like booleans and integers work like floats.)

Comment: When passing an array as an argument (by specifying the array name), the address of the first item in the array is passed. If I have a pointer to an array and pass the pointer as an argument, that *also* passes the address of the first item in the array. So in a discussion about passing arguments, I'm saying the array can work like a pointer.

Comment: @Jonathan: You cannot pass the address of an array as a pointer to the first element. That is, given `void f(int*);`, you cannot do `int a[50]; f(&a);` because `int(*)[50]` cannot be converted to `int*`.

Answer (score 3):

An array cannot be passed into functions by-value. Instead, it's converted to a pointer to the first element, and that's passed to the function. Having a (non-const) pointer to data allows modification:

```
void foo(int* i)
{
    if (i) (don't dereference null)
        *i = 5; // dereference pointer, modify int
}
```

Likewise, the function now has a pointer to a `TCHAR` it can write to. It takes the size, then, so it knows exactly how many `TCHAR`'s exist after that initial one. Otherwise it wouldn't know how large the array is.

Answer (score 2):

Following wrapper can be tried, if you want to avoid the size:

```
template<typename CHAR_TYPE, unsigned int SIZE>
void MyGetTempPath (CHAR_TYPE (&array)[SIZE])  // 'return' value can be your choice
{
  GetTempPath(SIZE, array);
}
```

Now you can use like below:

```
TCHAR tempPath[255];
MyGetTempPath(tempPath);  // No need to pass size, it will count automatically
```

In your other question, why we do NOT use following:

```
GetTempPath(buf &LPTSTR);
```

is because, `&` is used when you want to pass a data type by reference (not address). I am not aware what `buf` is typecasted to but it should be some pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

GetTempPath() outputs into your "tempPath" character array. If you don't tell it how much space there is allocated in the array (255), it has no way of knowing whether or not it will have enough room to write the path string into tempPath.

Character arrays in C/C++ are pretty much just pointers to locations in memory. They don't contain other information about themselves, like instances of C++ or Java classes might. The meat and potatoes of the Windows API was designed before C++ really had much inertia, I think, so you'll often have to use older C style techniques and built-in data types to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody provide a simple
>   GetTempPath implementation sample so I
>   can see how size is used?

First way (based on MAX_PATH constant):

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, szPath);
```

Second way (based on GetTempPath description):

```
DWORD size;
LPTSTR lpszPath;
size = GetTempPath(0, NULL);
lpszPath = new TCHAR[size];
GetTempPath(size, lpszPath);
/* some code here */
delete[] lpszPath;
```

> How can windows change the buf value without the & operator?

& operator is not needed because array name is the pointer to first array element (or to all array). Try next code to demonstrate this:

```
TCHAR sz[1];
if ((void*)sz == (void*)&sz) _tprintf(TEXT("sz equals to &sz \n"));
if ((void*)sz == (void*)&(sz[0])) _tprintf(TEXT("sz equals to &(sz[0]) \n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

As requested, a very simple implementation.

```
bool MyGetTempPath(size_t size, char* buf) 
{
    const char* path = "C:\\test\\";
    size_t len = strlen(path);

    if(buf == NULL)
        return false;

    if(size < len + 1)
        return false;

    strncpy(buf, path, size);

    return true;
}
```

An example call to the new function:

```
char buffer[256];
bool success = MyGetTempPath(256, buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx

```
DWORD WINAPI GetTempPath(
 __in   DWORD nBufferLength,
 __out  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

so  GetTempPath is defined something like

```
GetTempPath(DWORD nBufferLength, LPTSTR& lpBuffer);
```

What mean, that compiler passes the value lpBuffer by referenece.

Comment: The Windows API is pure C, and there are no reference types in C. The `__out` is just a hint for the (Microsoft) compiler and doesn't change the argument types at all.